# Movie about stories of different Asian women

Tags: identify-this-movie

The movie is probably a part-american, part-'asian' production. I don't know the specific country or the year. It looked older by quality, but in one part there were also small mobile phones (not bricks), and cars looking more like "2000 cars" than "1990 cars" in Google; I remember being surprised when I saw them. Most of the actors are Asian women. It's set in both Asia (the past) and States (present times). The language: I'm sure that some parts (maybe most of the movie) were non-English. It's in color (retrospections from long ago might be black and white but I'm not sure about that).

About the plot:
A few elderly women (a group of old friends) are sitting around a table and drinking tea. One of the group passed away recently and her (young) daughter is sitting with them instead. Then we watch their stories, there's probably one for each of them. I remember these:

- [just the ending:] One of these women was abused by her husband. She drowned their son (the only thing her husband cared about) in a washtub and run away.
- [full story:] The other woman's daughter married a successful/rich man, but had a very low self-esteem and didn't have any opinions or demands; the husband didn't like it so they were divorcing. Then the woman told her a story about her own childhood.

   -- Her father had two wifes and the first wife was considered "better" than others; she was a daughter of the second wife. The first wife didn't have children and gave a string of pearls to the second wife in exchange or as a sign that she will treat this kid as her own. But then the first wife got pregnant (i guess), so the second wife and her daughter were kicked out and had to sleep on the street, then the second wife died. At the funeral the kid was screaming and showing everyone the string of pearls to remind them their broken promise (and that they have no honor). So they had to take her back and treat with respect. -- so back to now, the daughter stopped feeling inferior to everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is [`Joy Luck Club`](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107282/):

from Wikipedia:

> Four older women, all Chinese immigrants living in San Francisco, meet
>   regularly to play mahjong, eat, and tell stories. Each of these women
>   has an adult Chinese-American daughter. The film reveals the hidden
>   pasts of the older women and their daughters and how their lives are
>   shaped by the clash of Chinese and American cultures as they strive to
>   understand their family bonds and one another.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks! I would have never guessed, even if I saw the trailer somewhere else.